# Save current time as a cookie in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, cookies, time, set

I am trying to get the time a user goes on a page and save it as a cookie (in JavaScript) I'm able to get the current time but I can't seem to be able to save it as a cookie.

The reason why I'm doing this is because I'd like to know how long it took my class to go from the first page to the last page of my training site. I collect the first time stamp when they load the first page, and I collect the second time stamp when they load the finale page (their are 5 pages). 
I'm not sure if there is a better way of doing this with Javascript?

Here is my code: (thanks in advance)

```js
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = d;
docCookies.setItem("time", "test");
```

```html
 <p id="test"></p>
```

Comment: What *is* `docCookies` ?

Comment: just a simple question: why would you want to do that?

Comment: May i know what error you are getting..?

Comment: And whatever `docCookies` actually is - you are not even passing the time (resp. your date object) to that function, but only two static values ... so what do you expect to happen …?

Comment: @GoltZ I'm tracking what time my team is going from page to page, thus using the time cookies everytime they load a new page.

Comment: @CBroe I'm not getting any error, it simply is not saving the cookie.

Comment: Well since you still have not enlightened us as to what `docCookies` actually is, you should not expect us to be able to provide any more insight on this either ...

Comment: @CBroe I was under the impression docCookies was where my cookies were being saved. (I'm still very new to HTML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code. This will add your current date in cookie.

```
var d = new Date();
document.cookie="time="+d;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
document.cookie = "name=John Doe; expires=Tue, 01 Aug 2017 12:00:00 UTC";
```

You can also go for Local Storage to store temporary data

```
localStorage.setItem("name", "John Doe");
```

Happy Coding...